# Palavras reescritas com outras letras mas mantendo os fonemas da língua

Tags: ortografia, fonemas

Existe algum termo que defina a reescrita de palavras usando outras letras, acentos, ou qualquer artifício da língua mas mantendo os mesmos fonemas?

Algumas vezes fazemos isso para reforçar a sílaba tônica, outras para enfatizar os fonemas; em alguns casos para soar apenas diferente ou engraçado, e em outros para reproduzir pronúncia de palavras estrangeiras.

Exemplos:

- Banãna: Para enfatizar a sílaba tônica e nasal em *banana*.
- Cârly: Pronúncia aproximada da palavra *curly* em Inglês.
- Ezemplo: Variação da pronúncia do "x" em exemplo.
- Deit: Pronúncia aproximada da palavra *date* em inglês.
- Assaum: Pronúncia da palavra "ação".
- Bála: Para enfatizar a sílaba tônica e a vogal A aberta.

E quando reescrevemos as palavras para reproduzir suas pronúncias em certos sotaques, ou pronúncias incorretas?

- Nóis: Pronúncia incorreta e informal de *nós*.
- Nóix: Ponúncia de nós onde o S soa como X.
- Ceis: Pronúncia reduzida e incorreta de *vocês*.
- Oncotô: Pronúncia de uma versão bem reduzida da frase "onde que eu estou" (é usada para descrever a forma de falar no Estado de Minas Gerais no Brasil).

Comment: "oncotô" é ótima.  E o bolo está dendoforno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. Em inglês é chamado de [*pronunciation respelling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling), que em português talvez seja "reescrita de pronúncia" (uma vez que não parece existir a palavra "ressoletrar" ou "re-ortografar"):

> A pronunciation respelling is a regular phonetic respelling of a word that does have a standard spelling, so as to indicate the pronunciation. Pronunciation respellings are sometimes seen in dictionaries.

Tradução livre:

> Uma *reescrita de pronúncia* é uma reescrita fonética regular de uma palavra que possui uma ortografia padrão, de modo a indicar sua pronúncia. Reescritas de pronúncia são por vezes vistas em dicionários.

Essa é uma versão específica de [transcrição fonética](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcri%C3%A7%C3%A3o_fon%C3%A9tica), sem a utilização de um dos alfabetos próprios:

> Uma transcrição fonética é um método mais ou menos formalizado de transcrever os sons de uma ou várias línguas.
>   Esta transcrição normalmente se aproxima de maneira padrão de pronunciar determinada língua.